# compare two NumPy array and edit one of them

Tags: python, arrays, compare, numpy-ndarray

```
a = array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
b = array([0,1,1,0,1,0])
```

I would like to compare the arrays and then edit array a with the condition, if value in b is 1 the value in a should stay the same, but if value in b is 0, the value in a should be 0 too.

so a should look like this:

```
a = array([0,2,3,0,5,0])
```

At the moment I'm trying to do it with this code:

```
for x,y in np.nditer([a,b], op_flags=['readwrite']):
                if y != 1.0:
                    x[...] = 0.0
```

but it's very slow. Is there a faster solution?

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: just multiply the arrays together eg ```a *= b```

Comment: How do you define "very slow"?

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below approach helps:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
b = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,0])
print(a*b)
```

Output:

```
[0 2 3 0 5 0]
```